# does this library assume the Google Spreadsheet will have one sheet only?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to use this library to pull data from a Googlespreadsheet with two sheets in it, I can get data only from the first sheet but not the second sheet. `sheet = client.open("sheetname").sheet1`, if I change sheet1 to sheet2 I get the following error `sheet = client.open("filename").sheet2 AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'sheet2'` how do I fix this? any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Marios Tag of `google-sheets-api` should be separated to the tags of `google-sheets` and `google-api`?

Comment: @Tanaike feel free to re-edit the tags. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Marios Thank you for replying. I'm not sure whether separating it is not correct and `google-sheets-api` is correct. I just wanted to know your thinking in order to obtain new information of the tags. And I want to include it to the future tags.

Comment: @Tanaike I agree with you. We should choose either google-sheets and google-api together or google-sheets-api alone.

Comment: @Marios Thank you for your opinion. When I saw the source script of gspread, it seems that `client.open()` uses Drive API for converting the spreadsheet name to spreadsheet ID. `get_worksheet()` uses Sheets API for retrieving the metadata of the spreadsheet. When it consider them, I thought that your combination of `google-sheets` and `google-api` might be better. Now, I noticed that `google-api` was not `google-apis`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sheet1` is used as a **shortcut**.

In order to get the **second** sheet try that:

```
sheet = client.open("filename").get_worksheet(1)
```

1 means second sheet (starting from 0).

**References:**

- [Official documentation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: Thank you @Marios This `sheet = client.open("filename").get_worksheet(1)` worked

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can use `get_worksheet`, `worksheet` and `worksheets`.

#### Sample script:

```
sh = client.open("###Spreadsheet name###")  # or client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)

worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(1)  # Use the index of the sheet. 0 is the 1st sheet.

worksheet = sh.worksheet('Sheet2')  # Use the sheet name of the sheet.

worksheet = sh.worksheets()[1]  # In this case, all sheets are included in the array.
```

#### Note:

- In the current stage, it seems that `sh.sheet1` is only the 1st sheet.

#### Reference:

- [Selecting a Worksheet](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#selecting-a-worksheet)